# Surface S is part of $x^2+y^2=1$ between planes $z=0$ and $x+y+z=2$. A vector field $F=\langle x,y,z\rangle$. Find the flux.

Tags: multivariable-calculus

> Surface S is part of $x^2+y^2=1$ between planes $z=0$ and $x+y+z=2$. A vector field $F=\langle x,y,z\rangle$. What is the value of integration
>   $$\iint_S F\cdot n \,dS $$
>   where $n$ is the unit normal vector of $S$.

Since the surface is not smooth, we cannot apply the divergence theorem here. Therefore, I calculate the flux on the following three surfaces separately.

(1) The cylinder $S_1$

I parametrize the cylinder surface as $r(z,\theta)=\langle \cos \theta, \sin \theta, z\rangle$. Then

$$\iint_{S_1} F\cdot n \,dS = \iint_D \langle x,y,z\rangle\cdot (r'_\theta \times r'_z)\,dA =\iint_D \langle x,y,z\rangle\cdot \langle \cos \theta, \sin \theta,0 \rangle \,dA =\iint_D \,dA$$

(2) The top plane $S_2:x+y+z=2$

$$\iint_{S_2} F\cdot n \,dS = \iint_D \langle x,y,z\rangle\cdot\langle 1,1, 1\rangle\,dA=\iint_D x+y+z \,dA $$
which is equal to
$$\iint_D 2 \,dA$$

(3) The bottom plane $S_3: z=0$

$$\iint_{S_3} F\cdot n \,dS = \iint_D \langle x,y,z\rangle\cdot\langle 0,0, 1\rangle\,dA=\iint_D z \,dA=0 $$

**Is my approach right?**

Now the answer is $\iint_D 3 \,dA$, which is the same as what the divergence theorem gives. Is it a coincidence? The surface is closed but not smooth.

Comment: It's no coincidence. The divergence theorem only requires the surface to be piecewise smooth. The surface in your prolem is piecewise smooth since the top plane, bottom plane, and cylindrical side are all smooth.